# Select/Join from multiple tables where tbl1.x = tbl2.x = tbl3.x

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I have a movie database and need to perform a query which returns all movies written, directed and produced by the same person.

I have many to many relations between movies->producers, movies->directors and movies->writers called movie_director, movie_producer and movie_writer. These tables have a foreign key to a table called persons and a  foreign key to a movies table.

How can I select movies which have **one** and the same producer,director and writer? I have tried this select statement but it returns a lot of duplicates:

```
SELECT movie_director.name
from movie_director, 
     movie_producer, 
     movie_writer
where movie_producer.name = movie_director.name = movie_writer.name;
```

**Create movie_director:**

```
CREATE TABLE `movie_director` (
  `title` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `year` int NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`title`, `year`, `name`),
  INDEX `fk_movies_has_directors_name_idx` (`name` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_movies_has_directors_titleyear_idx` (`title` ASC, `year` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_movies_has_directors_titleyear`
    FOREIGN KEY (`title` , `year`)
    REFERENCES `mdb`.`movies` (`title` , `year`)
    ON DELETE cascade
    ON UPDATE cascade,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_movies_has_directors_name`
    FOREIGN KEY (`name`)
    REFERENCES `mdb`.`directors` (`name`)
    ON DELETE cascade
    ON UPDATE cascade)
    ENGINE INNODB;
```

**Create movie_director:**

```
CREATE TABLE `movie_producer` (
 `title` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `year` int NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`title`, `year`, `name`),
  INDEX `fk_movies_has_producers_name_idx` (`name` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_movies_has_producers_titleyear_idx` (`title` ASC, `year` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_movies_has_producers_titleyear`
    FOREIGN KEY (`title` , `year`)
    REFERENCES `mdb`.`movies` (`title` , `year`)
    ON DELETE cascade
    ON UPDATE cascade,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_movies_has_producers_name`
    FOREIGN KEY (`name`)
    REFERENCES `mdb`.`producers` (`name`)
    ON DELETE cascade
    ON UPDATE cascade)
    ENGINE INNODB;
```

**Create movie_writer:**

```
CREATE TABLE `movie_writer` (
 `title` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `year` int NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`title`, `year`, `name`),
  INDEX `fk_movies_has_writers_name_idx` (`name` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_movies_has_writers_titleyear_idx` (`title` ASC, `year` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_movies_has_writers_titleyear`
    FOREIGN KEY (`title` , `year`)
    REFERENCES `mdb`.`movies` (`title` , `year`)
    ON DELETE cascade
    ON UPDATE cascade,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_movies_has_writers_name`
    FOREIGN KEY (`name`)
    REFERENCES `mdb`.`writers` (`name`)
    ON DELETE cascade
    ON UPDATE cascade)
    ENGINE INNODB;
```

Thankful for all help or links to helpful information!

Comment: Select `distinct` ...

Comment: Also use explict joins

Comment: How are movies identified in those 3 tables?

Comment: The movies table are identified using title and year. Those 3 tables reference the title and year from movies.

Comment: Just publish the schema with `show create table xxxx` for each. Don't hand type it or describe it. Put together a quality question

Comment: Added the create statements to my question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to join `movies` table with all the other three tables to find the the name of `producer ,director and writer` of any movie and
then you can filter the result where the name is same on all the fields.

As a side note never use old style comma separated join always use proper `Inner Join` syntax to join two or more tables

```
SELECT     movie_director.NAME 
FROM       movies m 
INNER JOIN movie_director md 
ON         m.movieid = md.movieid 
INNER JOIN movie_producer mp 
ON         m.movieid = mp.movieid movie_writer mw 
ON         m.movieid = mp.movieid 
WHERE      mp.NAME=md.NAME 
AND        mp.NAME=mw.NAME
```

Comment: Or just say `join`. We really need to see the schema as you are making a lot of assumptions here!

Comment: @reaanb - it looks like mysql supports `a=b=c` syntax that's why i removed

Comment: Modified it a bit since I don't use movieID but title and year instead. But this query seems to be working:

`SELECT     md.name as Director, mp.name as Producer, mw.name as Writer, m.title, m.year 
FROM       movies m 
INNER JOIN movie_director md 
ON         m.title = md.title AND m.year = md.year
INNER JOIN movie_producer mp 
ON         m.title = mp.title AND m.year = mp.year 
INNER JOIN movie_writer mw 
ON         m.title = mw.title AND m.year = mw.year 
WHERE      mp.name=md.name 
AND        mp.name=mw.name;`

Answer (score 0):

You can try group_concat. Reference doc http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat